# What is the equivalent way of doing this type of pythonic vectorized assignment in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, vectorization

I'm trying to translate this line of code from Python to MATLAB:

```
new_img[M[0, :] - corners[0][0], M[1, :] - corners[1][0], :] = img[T[0, :], T[1, :], :]
```

So, naturally, I wrote something like this:

```
new_img(M(1,:)-corners(2,1),M(2,:)-corners(2,2),:) = img(T(1,:),T(2,:),:);
```

But it gives me the following error when it reaches that line:

> Requested 106275x106275x3 (252.4GB) array exceeds maximum array size
>   preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long
>   time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or
>   preference panel for more information.

This has made me believe that it is not assigning things correctly. Img is at most a 1000 × 1500 RGB image. The same code works in less than 5 seconds in Python. How can I do vector assignment like the code in the first line in MATLAB?

By the way, I didn't paste all lines of my code for this post not to get too long. If I need to add anything else, please let me know.

**Edit:**
Here's an explanation of what I want my code to do (basically, this is what the Python code does):

Consider this line of code. It's not a real MATLAB code, I'm just trying to explain what I want to do:

```
A([2 3 5], [1 3 5]) = B([1 2 3], [2 4 6])
```

It is interpreted like this:

```
A(2,1) = B(1,2)
A(3,1) = B(2,2)
A(5,1) = B(3,2)
A(2,3) = B(1,4)
A(3,3) = B(2,4)
A(5,3) = B(3,4)
...
...
...
```

Instead, I want it to be interpreted like this:

```
A(2,1) = B(1,2)
A(3,3) = B(2,4)
A(5,5) = B(3,6)
```

Comment: Can you try with a 10x10 image and look at the resulting `new_img`? What does it look like?

Comment: @damienfrancois: I set the input to img = 255*ones(10,10,3, 'uint8'). What it gives back is all white as execpted. The result is 10 &times; 10 &times; 3 which looks OK. Does this reveal anything?

Comment: then you might need to validate that the inputs `M`, `corners`, and `T` have the correct dimension

Comment: @damienfrancois  I just debugged my code again. It seems that `M`, `corners` and `T` are the correct sizes. The problem starts when the assignment is done. For example, when T is of size (2, 59175), the size of img(T(1,:), T(2,:),:) is (59175,59175,3) which is not correct because the size of img should not be changed. I'm just trying to ask MATLAB to read/write only those entries that come from the values in the matrix T. I wish I'm not explaining it ambiguously. Is it clear what I'm trying to say?

Comment: it would be easier if you could provide a sample piece of code that we can run by ourself

Comment: @damienfrancois  I'm afraid my post will get too long. My original code in Python is more than 60 lines. I can paste it in my question if it fits. Is it possible to upload codes on stackoverflow for others to see it? Something with a scroll perhaps? I checked the tour section again but this wasn't mentioned.

Comment: no the idea would be to reduced it to the strict minimum that exhibits that unwanted behaviour. (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @damienfrancoiss Yes, but if you want to 'run it by yourself', you'll need all of the 60 lines or you won't be able to run it on your own. That's the strict minimum size in this case unfortunately. Anyway, I edited my post. Please check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `A[vector1, vector2]` in Python, you index the set:

```py
A[vector1[0], vector2[0]]
A[vector1[1], vector2[1]]
A[vector1[2], vector2[2]]
A[vector1[3], vector2[3]]
...
```

In MATLAB, the similar-looking `A(vector1, vector2)` instead indexes the set:

```matlab
A(vector1(1), vector2(1))
A(vector1(1), vector2(2))
A(vector1(1), vector2(3))
A(vector1(1), vector2(4))
...
A(vector1(2), vector2(1))
A(vector1(2), vector2(2))
A(vector1(2), vector2(3))
A(vector1(2), vector2(4))
...
```

That is, you get each combination of indices. You should think of it as a sub-array composed of the rows and columns specified in the two vectors.

To accomplish the same as the Python code, you need to use linear indexing:

```matlab
index = sub2ind(size(A), vector1, vector2);
A(index)
```

Thus, your MATLAB code should do:

```matlab
index1 = sub2ind(size(new_img), M(1,:)-corners(2,1), M(2,:)-corners(2,2));
index2 = sub2ind(size(img), T(1,:), T(2,:));

% these indices are for first 2 dims only, need to index in 3rd dim also:
offset1 = size(new_img,1) * size(new_img,2);
offset2 = size(img,1) * size(img,2);
index1 = index1.' + offset1 * (0:size(new_img,3)-1);
index2 = index2.' + offset2 * (0:size(new_img,3)-1);

new_img(index1) = img(index2);
```

What the middle block does here is add linear indexes for the same elements along the 3rd dimension. If `ii` is the linear index to an element in the first channel, then `ii + offset1` is an index to the same element in the second channel, and `ii + 2*offset1` is an index to the same element in the third channel, etc. So here we're generating indices to all those matrix elements. The `+` operation is doing implicit singleton expansion (what they call "broadcasting" in Python). If  you have an older version of MATLAB this will fail, you need to replace that `A+B` with `bsxfun(@plus,A,B)`.

Comment: It might be worth noting that code ports should only ever be performed in the opposite direction; i.e. from MATLAB to python, and never the other way around.

Comment: Thanks. So, it turns out that my edit was wrong then. I'm glad that you still figured what I was looking for. Could you please add how the assignment should be done? Would it be `new_img(index1) = img(index2)` where `index1 = sub2ind(size(M), M(1,:), M(2,:))` and `index2 = sub2ind(size(T), T(1,:), T(2,:))`?

Comment: `sub2ind(size(M), M(1,:), M(2,:))` gives `Out of range subscript`. :(

Comment: @stressedout: sorry for the confusion with my choice of `M`, I gave it a different meaning from yours... I've added explicit code for you to use. There is some complication that I glossed over regarding the third index...

Comment: @stressedout: Ah, sorry, your `index1` is a row vector, of course. It needs to be transposed. See the edit. I've also added some explanation for this part of the code. It's more complex than it should be, really. I guess Python's solution is prettier. :)

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand better. I do have an older version of MATLAB, so I used bsxfun as you suggested. However, I think it's still not working because colors are weird. For example, white color is seen as red. So, the color channels are still not transformed correctly. MATLAB is too complicated. Ironically, my friends said that MATLAB is easier than Python, but I can't disagree more.

Comment: @stressedout: A few things are easier in MATLAB, a few things are easier in Python. Most of it is similar enough, and what is easier then depends on what you're used to. Anyway, I don't know what else could be problematic. I just noticed I was missing some parenthesis, could that be it?

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thanks for all your help. I've learned a lot today and I need some time to digest it all. Again, thanks.