# MATLAB memory problem when accessing and copying the 3D array elements by subscripts

Tags: matlab, memory, memory-management

I am trying to access/copy values from an image 3D array to another 3D array using the subscripts (rows and columns). I am trying to avoid the for loop. With for loop this works fine. The size of the rows and columns is 121020 x 1. But I am getting a memory error as below:

```
Requested 121020x121020x3 (40.9GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive.
```

The code snippet is below:

```
% Find boundary of the cylindrical projection
[row,col] = find(ximg > 0 & ximg <= xdim & yimg > 0 & yimg <= ydim);
out(row,col,:) = image(row,col,:);
```

`ximg` and `yimg` are 2D array of size `384 x 512` pixels. `image` is `384 x 512 x 3` pixels. –

Any help to make it without for loop is appreciated!

Comment: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53750283/7328782) might be about the same problem. Does that help you?

Comment: `ximg` and `yimg` are 2D array of size `384 x 512` pixels. `image` is `384 x 512 x 3` pixels.

Answer (score 1):

As I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53751113/7328782), `A(row,col)` selects all rows specified in `row`, and all columns specified in `col`, basically giving you the outer product of the two (all possible combinations of one value in `row` and one in `col`). For example, `A(1:end,1:end)` doesn’t select only the diagonal elements ((1,1),(2,2),(3,3),…), it selects all elements.

Typically you don’t need to use `find` at all, you can use the binary image directly to index:

```
mask = A > 0;
A(mask) = 0;
```

However, you have a 3D image and a 2D mask, which means we need to do a bit more work. These are the two simplest options:

```
mask = img(:,:,1) < 0;  % a 2D mask
mask = repmat(mask,1,1,3); % mask has same size as img
img(mask) = 0;          % modify image
```

or

```
mask = img(:,:,1) < 0;  % a 2D mask
for ii=1:3
   tmp = img(:,:,ii);   % extract plane
   tmp(mask) = 0;       % modify it
   img(:,:,ii) = tmp;   % put it back
end
```

In the answer I linked above I show a more complex method working with indices into the matrix. That option might be more efficient if there are few pixels to modify, but I’m not sure. The only way to know is to measure for your specific case.

---

For example, for your specific case, you could do

```
mask = ximg > 0 & ximg <= xdim & yimg > 0 & yimg <= ydim;
mask = repmat(mask,1,1,3);
out(mask) = image(mask);
```